# Prove that $\operatorname{null}T^m=\operatorname{null}T^{m+1}$ if and only if $\operatorname{range}T^m=\operatorname{range}T^{m+1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

$\newcommand{\range}{\operatorname{range}}\newcommand{\null}{\operatorname{null}}$Problem: Suppose $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ and $m$ is a nonnegative integer. Prove that $\null T^m=\null T^{m+1}$ if and only if $\range T^m=\range T^{m+1}$.

Here is what I have so far.

($\Rightarrow$) Let $\null T^m=\null T^{m+1}$. I have already shown $\range T^m\supset\range T^{m+1}$, so I need to show $\range T^m\subset\range T^{m+1}$. Let $v\in\range T^m$, so there is some $u\in V$ such that $v=T^mu$.

Need to show there is some $s\in V$ such that $v=T^{m+1}s$.

($\Leftarrow$) Let $range T^m=\range T^{m+1}$. I already know that $\null T^m\subset\null T^{m+1}$ from a theorem (and it's easy to show), so I need to show $\null T^m\supset\null T^{m+1}$. Let $v\in\null T^{m+1}$, so $T^{m+1}v=0$.

Need to show $T^mv=0$.

I'm not really looking for an answer so much as being steered in the right direction. I understand what it means for $\null T^m=\null T^{m+1}$, but am unsure of what to do with it or the ranges being equal in the second part. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is V  a finite dimensional vector space?

Comment: No, it could be infinite dimensional. Otherwise, lhf's response would work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point is that if $U \subseteq U'$ and $\dim U = U'$ then $U=U'$.

Since you already know the inclusions, use the kernel-image equation (aka rank–nullity theorem) to get equality.

Comment: I appreciate the response, lhf. However, this assumes finite dimensions, does it not? I don't believe that is an assumption that we can make here.

Comment: @NBrown, perhaps replace the rank–nullity theorem by $\operatorname{range} T \simeq V/\operatorname{null} T$ and use the correspondence between subspaces of the range and subspace that contain the kernel.